# Infopath 2010 SharePoint 2010: Kind of Cascading Dropdowns

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm looking for a solution of the following question.

I have a mainlist with information about people.

**Name -- OrgaLevel1 -- OrgaLevel2**

Wilson -- ... -- ...

I have also a list with the organisation of a company:

**OrgaLevel1 -- Orgalevel2**

Orga A -- Orga AA
Orga A -- Orga AB
Orga B -- Orga BA
Orga B -- Orga BA

I like to build the form for the mainlist like this

Name:

OrgaLevel1:

OrgaLevel2:

The values of the OrgaLevel2-DropDown should depend of the value I've selected in the OrgaLevel2-DropDown.

So if I selected OrgaA there should only be Orga AA and Orga AB in the second DropDown-List.

I hope, I have explained my problem understandable?!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you mean: you need cascading combobox. see this [template](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=9c328512bb163014&resid=9C328512BB163014!127&parid=9C328512BB163014!126).
you can extend this template more than 2 comboboxes